# Application of Law of Iterated Expectations to CEF-Decomposition Property

Tags: econometrics

In the "Mostly Harmless Econometrics" Chapter 3, with Theorem 3.1.1 The CEF-Decomposition Property, the author explains $E(h(X_i)e_i) = E\{h(X_i)E[e_i|X_i]\}$ because of the Law of Iterated Expectations, when $h(X_i)$ is any function of $X_i$.

By googling, I saw that there are steps in reaching the final term:
\begin{align*}
E[h(X_i)e_i]&=E[E[h(X_i)e_i|X_i]] \\
&=E[h(X_i)E[e_i|X_i]] \\
&=E{h(X_i)E[e_i|X_i]}
\end{align*}

However, I have difficulty in understanding "$E[E[h(X_i)e_i|X_i]] = E[h(X_i)E[e_i|X_i]]$". How $h(X_i)$ can be popped out of the bracket even if it is a function of $X_i$???

Comment: In $E(h(X_i) e_i \mid X_i)$ since the expectation is conditional on the variable $X_i$, any function of $X_i$ is considered to be constant and can then be moved out that expectation.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=conditional+expectation+"take+out"++known

Comment: @periwinkle Great thanks for explanation

Comment: @whuber I appreciate for related term and concept. I missed basic thing.